# How to increase the width of EditingStyle Button / Swipe To Delete Button in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

How can we increase the default width of EditingStyle Button / Swipe Buttons in UITableView?

Answer (score 0):

Since the width of Editing Style Button depends on the title, you can use a blank unicode character \u{3164} to add empty characters and increase the width. Here's what I did:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

            let contextItem = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "  \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164} \u{3164}") {  (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
}
                
 }
```